# File picker opens without button click on subwindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, appjar

I want to show a login screen. Once login is successful, I want to show a window with a button. If I click on the button a file picker should open.

With my code, what happens is that after logging in correctly, the file picker opens directly, instead of, when a button is clicked. If file picker is closed, main window and another window with the button is shown. What is wrong with my code? How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
from appJar import gui
app = gui()

def AuthenticationDetails(user, passw):
    if user=="myuser" and passw=="mypass":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def press(button):
    usr = app.getEntry("Username")
    pwd = app.getEntry("Password")
    print("User:", usr, "Pass:", pwd)
    if AuthenticationDetails(usr, pwd):
        Success()
    else:
        app.errorBox("Failed login", "Invalid username or password")

def Success():
    print("Successfully logged in")


def login(btn):
    # app.hideSubWindow("Login")
    app.showSubWindow("Main", hide=True)
    app.buttons(["Choose file"], [choosefile(app)])
    # app.addButton("Choose File", choosefile(app))
    app.show()

def choosefile(app):
    print("Opening Choose file")
    app.openBox(title="Choose P1 form pdf file", dirName=None, fileTypes=None, asFile=False, parent="Main")


app.startSubWindow("Login")
app.label("Enter login details", bg='blue', fg='white')
app.entry("Username", label=True, focus=True)
app.entry("Password", label=True, secret=True)
app.buttons(["Submit", "Cancel"], [login, app.stop])
app.stopSubWindow()

app.startSubWindow("Main", title="ESI Superspecialty Reference Helper v1.0")
app.label("Your login was successful", bg='blue', fg='white')
app.setSize("400x200")
app.setBg("blue")
app.setFg("white")
app.stopSubWindow()
app.go(startWindow="Login")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `login()` function is calling the `chooseFile()` function, rather than passing it as a callback argument.

Get rid of the `app` parameter in the `chooseFile()` function, then don't include any brackets or an argument when you assign `chooseFile` to the button.